# How can i get Attributes Values on sales_flat_order_grid after insert new custom column

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order, table, custom-column-grid

I have insert column: warehouse in sales_flat_order_grid.[And also created attributes with values] After added how can i get the attributes values,

```
 //workout
 $this->addColumn('warehouse', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Warehouse'),
        'index' => 'warehouse',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',          

        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'warehouse'),

    ));
```

How to solve the error?

Comment: You want to display the values of a product attribute as an option array in the admin orders grid ? I trully suggest you don't do that.

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis : Then how can i choose, this order for this warehouse, how can i assign the order? Did you get my point?

Comment: No actually I don't. In your case 'warehouse' is a product attribute. How can you filter an order with multiple products with different warehouses?

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis : Not for individual products, only order. if order placed admin point out this order to this warehouse, this is what i need.

Comment: If not possible, how can i achieved it, is any other possibilities exist. actually, i created column name on the table also, but not getting the result.

Comment: First, you need to add a custom atttribute to your order. Then you need to create a model for this attribute and probably a table to store your options. Then add this attribute to your grid and create a model with a "toOptionArray" or (sth like this) function. Still you need to alter your order's bavkend or frontend to accomodate a field for your custom option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67636/discussion-between-zus-and-yiorgos-moschovitis).